# Python 3 Popen calling rrdtool hangs indefinitely

Tags: subprocess, python-3.4, rrdtool

I am trying to use Python's `Popen()` to retrieve graph data from a multiple rrd files. Due to complexity of app where the following piece of code is utilised, I rely on rrdtool graph parameter -Z for handling missing files for me:

```
#!/bin/python3

import subprocess

cmd = '/opt/rrdtool/bin/rrdtool graph - -a JSONTIME -Z --width 924 --start 1486428000 --end 1486471200 DEF:foo1=ch1.rrd:flows:MAX DEF:foo2=ch2.rrd:flows:MAX  AREA:foo1#000:"ch1" AREA:foo2#606060:"ch2":STACK'
path = '/data/live/pokus/rrd/channels/'

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=path, shell=True)
p.wait()
if p.returncode is not 0:
    print("Error")
else:
    print(p.stdout.read().decode(encoding="utf-8"))
```

Following code works as expected when both files ch1.rrd and ch2.rrd are present. When one of them is missing, whole thing hangs indefinitely until I kill the rrdtool process manually from htop. Then python detects nonzero return code and reports error.

Using `shell=False` and `shlex.split()` on `cmd` does not help.

When I execute the same command from bash, even with the missing files rrdtool does the job as expected.

Unfortunately I can't use rrdtool bindings for python and also I am stuck on python 3.4.5. `rrdtool` version is 1.6.0.

I am glab for any idea how to overcome this. I would prefer solution that does not include testing whether files exist from python and keeps the -Z parameter in `rrdtool` command. Also using timeout on `p.wait()` isn't a viable solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try capturing STDERR in your `subprocess.Popen()` call as well (i.e. `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

The reason why Python (namely `p.wait`) hanged was because rrdtool did not know the minimum step size (parameter `-S`) resulting in step size of two seconds. This way, output of the rrdtool was able to fill the OS buffers and that deadlocked `p.wait`. According to Python docs, `Popen.communicate` should be a way to go.